# How can i toggle Caps Lock LED by a program

Tags: caps-lock

Is there any way to toggle Caps Lock LED by a shell command or a script or a prgram on OSX 10.10?

All the solutions i goggled do not work on Yosemite.

I have mapped pressing Caps Lock to toggle keyboard layouts so i wanted to use the LED as an indicator of the present keyboard layout.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/285103/is-it-possible-to-control-the-caps-lock-led-on-os-x might be of help

Comment: @vihan so far the solutions given there do not work on Yosemite

Comment: did you make you were running them as root?

Answer (score 1):

MacLight is a Ruby Script which has worked for me.

https://github.com/busyloop/maclight